# flask relationship, unique column name only for same person

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What I want is that the same person can not have a dog with the same name, but if there can be that same name of a dog in other owners

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    pets = db.relationship('Pet',backref='person',lazy='dynamic')

class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

for example in the Person table there are these names ['fran','larson','pedro'] and the idea is that there may be 3 pets with the same name in the Pets table but never relate more than one pet with the same name to a person for example

pets_fran = ['name_pet_1','name_pet_2'] <--- correct

pets_larson = ['name_pet_4','name_pet5','name_pet_4'] <--- Deny this because you have two pets with the same name

pets_pedro = ['name_pet_1','name_pet_6','name_pet_7']  <--- the mascots of pedro and fran have the same name but are admitted because they have different owners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [**`UniqueConstraint`**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint) to the `Pet` table:

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('person.id'))

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('owner_id', 'name'),)
```

So now if you use this to construct the tables, it will (try) to enforce that the tuples (name, owner_id) in the entire column are unique. So in other words, one can not add two entries where both the name and owner_id are the same.